# $f\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=\left(1+z^2\right)f(z)$, solve $f$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

### Problem

Given $f$ is smooth and defined on $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$, $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ exists and it satisfies

$$f\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=\left(1+z^2\right)f(z).\tag {*}$$

Solve $f$.

---

**First attempt**

I tried to extend $f$ to all real number arguments by substituting $z=\frac{1}{t}$,

$$f\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)=\left(1+\frac1{t^2}\right)f\left(\frac1t\right).\tag {1.1}$$

Therefore, $\forall z\in(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$,

$$f(z)=\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right).\tag {1.2}$$

Let $g(z)=zf(z)$,

$$g(z)=g\left(\frac1z\right).\tag {1.3}$$

How can this be continued?

---

**Second attempt**

I notice
$$\tanh2x=\frac{2\tanh x}{1+\tanh^2x}.\tag {2.1}$$

Let $g(z)=zf(z)$ again, then

$$g\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=2g(z).\tag {2.2}$$

Put $z=\tanh x$,

$$g(\tanh2x)=2g(\tanh x).\tag {2.3}$$

Write $h(x)=g(\tanh x)$,

$$h(2x)=2h(x).\tag {2.4}$$

$$\therefore h(x)=cx, \forall c\in \mathbb R.$$

$\therefore g(x)$ is the inverse of $\tanh\dfrac xc$.

> $$\therefore f(z)=\frac{c \text{ arctanh } z}{z}, \forall c\in \mathbb R.\tag {**}$$

As putting $\tanh x$ is not the general method, I want to see other ways of solving the problem.

---

**Third attempt**

$$f\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=\left(1+z^2\right)f(z).$$

Let $h(z)=zf(z)$,
$$h\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=2h(z).\tag {3.1}$$

Assume the power series

$$h(z)=c_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k z^k.\tag {3.2}$$

I try to find the coefficients of $h$.

Then
$$h\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=c_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k \left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)^k.\tag {3.3}$$

$$h\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=c_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k 2^k z^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{n} \left(-z^2\right)^n$$
$$h\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=c_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 2^k c_k \binom{n+k-1}{n} z^{2n+k}.\tag {3.4}$$

Let $m=2n+k$, since $n\in\left[0,\lfloor{m-1\rfloor}/2\right]$,
$$h\left(\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\right)=c_0+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor{m-1\rfloor}/2} (-1)^n 2^{m-2n} c_{m-2n} \binom{m-n-1}{n} z^m.\tag {3.5}$$

> **Claim 1:** $$\forall k\in \mathbb N,c_{2k}=0.$$

The statement can be proved by mathematical induction.

Compare constant term on both sides in $(3.1)$, $c_0=2c_0\Rightarrow c_0=0.$

From $(3.5)$, since $c_{2k+2}$ is derived from the linear combination of $c_0,c_2,c_4,\cdots,c_{2k}$, it follows that $c_{2k+2}=0$. **Claim 1** is established.

> **Claim 2:** $$\forall k\in \mathbb N,c_{2k+1}=\frac{c_1}{2k+1}.$$

How can **Claim 2** be proven?

---

**Fourth attempt**

I think of the following equation and try to solve it:

$$g\left(\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right)=g(x)+g(y).\tag {***}$$

We can arrive $(2.2)$ by setting $x=y=z$.

Let $W(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$, $R(u,v)=u+v$.

Rewrite $(***)$ as

$$g\left(W(x,y)\right)=R\left(g(x),g(y)\right).\tag {4.1}$$

Could $g$ in $(4.1)$ be solved through **partial derivatives**?

---

Apart from above attempts, any other thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Small, relatively irrelevant, technical nitpick: $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ is not an interval.

Comment: @Nij Thanks for your editing:)

Comment: Why are you assuming that $f$ is differentiable? What if it doesn't have a power series?

Comment: @MichaelLee It's my mistake, the question is updated. $f$ is smooth.

Comment: The solutions depends heavily upon specifying boundary conditions, if any. There is nothing assumed about the behavior at $z=0$ or $z=\pm 1$?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Updated: $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ exists.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything with your first attempt. What I mean is, if you find function $g$ such that $g(z) = g(1/z)$ on $(0,+\infty)$, there is no guarantee that $f(z) = g(z)/z$ will satisfy $(*)$. You can check this by setting $g(z) = 2z/(1+z^2)$.

Comment: The problem with your first approach is that the domain of $f$ is $(-1,1)$, but if $z \in (-1,1)$ then $1/z$ is not in $(-1,1)$ so $g(1/z)$ is not even defined.

Comment: As for the second attempt, substitution $z = \tanh z$ is good because $\tanh:\mathbb R\to (-1,1)$ is bijection and thus $f(z) = h(\operatorname{arctanh} z)/z$. However, does $h(2x) = 2h(x)$ really imply $h(x) = cx$? I mean, it is not Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: @Winther, it looks that OP wanted to extend definition of $f$ on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ with $x\mapsto 1/x$, and try to find solution there. However, as my comment says, this latter solution on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ needs not solve the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for editing the solution by WORD.[image: solution]

Answer (score 5):

Given that the limit $c=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f(z)$ is assumed to exist (but $f$ is not assumed e.g. analytic at zero) a dynamical systems approach using the $\tanh$ substitution is probably the easiest. 
You have for $z$ non-zero $$ f \left( \frac{2z}{1+z^2} \right) =  2z\frac{1+z^2}{2z} f(z)$$
Setting $z=\tanh t/2$, $t\in {\Bbb R}\setminus \{0\}$ the above reads:  $$f(\tanh(t)) = \frac{2 \tanh(t/2)}{\tanh(t)} f(\tanh (t/2))$$
Iterating this relation $n$ times:
 $$f(\tanh(t)) = \frac{2^n \tanh(2^{-n} t)}{\tanh(t)} f(\tanh (2^{-n}t))\rightarrow \frac{t }{\tanh t} c$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. It follows that $f(\tanh(t))=ct/\tanh(t)$ or $$f(z)=c  \frac{{\rm Arctanh} \;z}{z}.$$